# Scala Error : missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file

Tags: scala

**below is the json response** ,

```
{
  "enrollment_terms": [
    {
      "end_at": null,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Default Term",
      "start_at": null,
      "workflow_state": "active",
      "sis_term_id": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**//Case Classes for Response**

```
case class AccountTerms(enrollment_terms: List[enrollmentTerms])
case class enrollmentTerms(end_at: String, id: String, name: String, start_at: String, workflow_state: String, sis_term_id: String)
```

**//Scala Code :**

```
 val accountTerm = json.extract[AccountTerms]
```

**//Error at Line**

```
 val terms = accountTerm.enrollment_terms
```

// **Error** : missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'AccountTerms.class'.
 Could not access type enrollmentTerms in package com.abc.pqr.jobs,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'AccountTerms.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of  com.abc.pqr.jobs

Comment: It's weird... it works just perfect for me. Might be some name clashing in your classpath? Is there any other `AccountTerms`?

Comment: no , one & only one **AccountTerms**

Comment: Both case classes are under the same package?

Comment: yes , in fact in the same file.

Comment: Do you use sbt? Could you show your build.sbt?

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jdbc, cache, ws, evolutions, filters, specs2 % Test)

libraryDependencies ++= Build.LIBS

logLevel := Level.Error

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")

fork in run := false


fork in run := true